# Bounty timer too short?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Q: Is the bounty timer of 1 week too short for Skeptics?

I recently offered a bounty on [a question i am interested in](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14381/is-there-such-a-thing-as-leisure-sickness), but the answers provided were not good enough by the time the bounty expired. I have done several bounties on Stackoverflow and its a good way to not have the question disappear in the huge flood of questions there.

I believe the situation here on Skeptics is different. 'Easy ' to answer questions are usually addressed by the awesome community here quickly. But questions that are not as easy or lack the studies to support answers may take a lot longer. Maybe (if technically possible) it would be better to allow the bounty to stay open longer.

Answer (score 1):

Good point.  I too have had bounties expire.  Given the exacting standards we have, it would be a good idea to see if we can expand the time-frame for bounties.  Let me pass this along.